# Pacing concept implementation in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, timers are used to have variable time gaps  between requests.
But how can I bring various time gaps between users , ( the concept is pacing)?I hopeI am clear in asking .Please explain. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Test Action" Sampler for achieving Pacing.

Comment: Thank you it is working but with test action i am able to pause for a fixed time between all users , how can i achieve different time pauses.

Comment: You can use _Random function by specifying the boundaries and put it in testAction "Duration(Milliseconds) " field